# How to shrink Large title when UICollectionView (inside horizontal CollectionView) scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios11, preferslargetitles

I am using Brian's (LBTA) [youtube demo](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course/YouTube) to create Scrollable Horizontal MenuBar.

I am using `collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` to avoid warnings in debug area.

I just want to add `Large title` which was introduced with iOS 11.

Set `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` to enable Large Title. And it is working well as expected.

Now, I want to shrink Large Title to normal title, when scrolling UIcollectionView (which is inside horizontal UICollectionView).

How to connect scrollView (inside UICollectionView's scroll) to NavigationController/NavigationItem to shrink?

[image]

Comment: As i know Large title looks for the first scrollView in the view hierarchy. Bug first scroll view does not scroll vertically, so you can place dummy scrollView as a first scrollView in the view hierarchy and reflect the currently scrolling scrollViews's content inset and content size on it. Just an idea, maybe helps.

Comment: Great question JD. We just got stuck on it also. Did you solve it? We are pulling hairs..

Comment: Do you have any update on this implementation?

Comment: No man. Hope SwiftUI will help us